# Is GeoPDF suitable for mobile-navigation app?

Tags: android, mobile, ios, geopdf

I need to develop mobile app that display geo-referenced image. User should be able see own position on it and do simple navigation. Plus turn on/off vector layers.

Now I am looking format/mobile component that allow to do this offline.

Is geoPDF suitable for it?

Answer (score 2):

For very simple and small maps it may be fine your better off using MBTILES or GPKG GEOPACKAGE TILES
You can use GDAL to produce these or QGIS. Just note if you choose MBTILES first re project data to spherical web Mercator EPSG 3857. If you have vector data use vector tiles MBTILES using Tippecanoe or geopackage features.